# Control positon when replacing the content of a smart object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

Let's say I have a smart object at the top-left corner of my picture, as shown in the first capture:

[image: square in top left corner]

If I replace the content of this smart object (right click > Replace Contents…) with an image that doesn't have the same proportions than the original one, the smart object is resized from the center, as shown in the second capture:

[image: rectangle not quite in top left]

Question: is there a way to specify the anchor point from which the smart object will resize when replacing its content?